# A very bizarre output I got from int x[3];

Tags: c++, initialization

So I typed the code below in C++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int x[3];
    cout << x[1] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and when I run it, it prints out -272632344 instead of 0. Any reason why?

Comment: C adheres to the rule that you don't pay for what you don't ask for. C++ inherits much from C. Since you didn't ask for the array to be initialized it wasn't, because that would have taken some extra cycles.

Comment: *A very bizarre output* -- Nope, not bizarre.

Comment: Why would it be 0?

Answer (score 5):

In [default initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization),

> if T is an array type, every element of the array is default-initialized;

Then

> otherwise, nothing is done: the objects with automatic storage duration (and their subobjects) are initialized to indeterminate values.

Trying to print out these indeterminate values leads to [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

If you want all the elements to be initialized to zero, you might want [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), e.g.

```
int foo [3] = {}; // all the elements will be value-initialized to zero
int foo [3] {};   // same as above
```

Comment: default-initialized... meaning all those elements will get 0 for their values just like in Java? or they'll get "random values" ? unlike Java?

Comment: @NewLearner: It says "otherwise, nothing is done". The initial values are not *random* (that word has a specific meaning), they're *indeterminate*. Think of them as arbitrary. (They might happen to be zero if you're unlucky. I say "unlucky" because that makes it difficult to detect the error.)

Comment: but I clicked on your link and read it and it said if T is an array type, every element will be default-initialized instead of 'nothing will be done'. correct me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: @NewLearner C++ is not Java; in C++, if you just write some thing like `int a;` inside a function, `a` will have indeterminate value.

Comment: @NewLearner It says every element will be default-initialized, i.e. every `int`s. These `int`s are neither class type (the 1st case) nor array type (the 2nd case), then the 3rd case gets applied, "otherwise...".

Comment: @NewLearner *unlike Java?* -- Do **not** use Java as a model in writing or understanding C++ code.  You will just get confused when things don't work the same way, or worse, you start to write C++ code that attempts to be Java code, causing all sorts of havoc.

Comment: @songyuanyao you said i.e. every int, and I'm thinking elements of int x[3]; are indeed int type. are they not? so because those elements of int x[3]; are integers, they will get default initialized. right?

Comment: @KeithThompson I would say that "indeterminate value" is a distinct state from any non-indeterminate value , and therefore is not 0 or any other concrete value

Comment: @NewLearner Yes, these integers will get default initialized; and the effect is that they're initialized to indeterminate value. *Default initialization* != *being initialized to 0*. We have to follow the rules of default initialization of C++. If you don't want it, you could change to other initializations, like value initialization.

Comment: oh alright. that makes sense. before you just kept saying it will do nothing but you didn't really explain what default initialization would do but now I understand. thanks.

Comment: @NewLearner the second quote in this answer explains what default initialization does (for `int`) and there is also a link to full reference on the first line of this answer

Comment: @NewLearner Glad to hear that. Good luck (for learning initialization of C++).

Answer (score 1):

The array is not initialized, it gets random values currently in the memory.

You can initialize an array like this:

```
int foo [3] = { 0, 0, 0 };
```

Also see "Initializing arrays" section [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/):

> By default, regular arrays of local scope (for example, those declared within a function) are left uninitialized. This means that none of its elements are set to any particular value; their contents are undetermined at the point the array is declared.

Comment: Alright. so in Java(I'm from Java background), all the int array elements are automatically 0 even if you don't initialize it but in C++, they get random values.. so that's why I got confused. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yea in C++ when defining `int a[3]`, compiler assigns three consecutive memory blocks each size of an int. But those memory blocks won't get initialized, and will have the value that currently have in your case value of x[3] in the memory was `-272632344`